# How do I fix "The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened" during an update?

Tags: apt, update-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Problem with MergeList” error when trying to do an update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30072/problem-with-mergelist-error-when-trying-to-do-an-update)

I have a problem with the update-manager.
It gives the following message error:

> E:Encountered a section with no Package: header, E:Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/dk.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_maverick_universe_binary-i386_Packages, E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.