# How to remove corrupted repositories?

Tags: 11.04, ppa, repository

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Problem with MergeList” error when trying to do an update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30072/problem-with-mergelist-error-when-trying-to-do-an-update)

I was in the process of updating 11.04 and came across and error message saying:

```
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_natty-security_main_i18n_Translation-en
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

I tried to remove the damage repository by going to ubuntu software center. There was no option of repository removal. Then I tried synaptic, however I got the same error message stated above. I cannot find software source in 11.04.

How do I remove repository from the commandline since that seems to be my only option?