# How to fix "Problem with MergeList" error when running an update?

Tags: apt, package-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Problem with MergeList” error when trying to do an update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30072/problem-with-mergelist-error-when-trying-to-do-an-update)

After "sudo apt-get update" in terminal, I get:

```
58% [99 Translation-en lzma 0 B] [Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.88.45)]                                                                                                                                              16.4 kB/s 4s/usr/bin/lzma: Decoder error
58% [100 Translation-en_NZ lzma 0 B] [Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.88.45)]                                                                                                                                          16.4 kB/s 4s/usr/bin/lzma: Decoder error
58% [101 Translation-en lzma 0 B] [Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.88.45)]                                                                                                                                             16.4 kB/s 4s/usr/bin/lzma: Decoder error
58% [102 Translation-en_NZ lzma 0 B] [Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.88.45)]                                                                                                                                          16.4 kB/s 4s/usr/bin/lzma: Decoder error
58% [103 Translation-en lzma 0 B] [Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.88.45)]                                                                                                                                             16.4 kB/s 4s/usr/bin/lzma: Decoder error
58% [104 Translation-en_NZ lzma 0 B] [Waiting for headers]/usr/bin/lzma: Decoder error                                                                                                                                                      
58% [105 Translation-en lzma 0 B] [Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.88.45)]/usr/bin/lzma: Decoder error
58% [106 Sources lzma 0 B] [Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.88.45)]/usr/bin/lzma: Decoder error
58% [107 Sources lzma 0 B] [Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.88.45)]/usr/bin/lzma: Decoder error
58% [108 Sources lzma 0 B] [42 Sources lzma 0 B]/usr/bin/lzma: Decoder error
58% [109 Sources lzma 0 B] [47 Sources lzma 0 B]/usr/bin/lzma: Decoder error
58% [110 Sources lzma 0 B] [Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.88.45)]/usr/bin/lzma: Decoder error
58% [111 Sources lzma 0 B] [Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.88.45)]/usr/bin/lzma: Decoder error
58% [112 Sources lzma 0 B] [Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.88.45)]/usr/bin/lzma: Decoder error
58% [113 Sources lzma 0 B] [114 Packages xz 0 B]/usr/bin/lzma: Decoder error
58% [114 Packages lzma 0 B] [Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.88.45)]/usr/bin/lzma: Decoder error
58% [115 Packages lzma 0 B] [Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.88.45)]/usr/bin/lzma: Decoder error
58% [116 Packages lzma 0 B] [Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.88.45)]/usr/bin/lzma: Decoder error
58% [117 Packages lzma 0 B] [Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.88.45)]/usr/bin/lzma: Decoder error
58% [118 Translation-en_NZ lzma 0 B] [Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.88.45)]/usr/bin/lzma: Decoder error
58% [119 Translation-en lzma 0 B] [Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.88.45)]/usr/bin/lzma: Decoder error
58% [120 Translation-en_NZ lzma 0 B] [Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.88.45)]/usr/bin/lzma: Decoder error
58% [121 Translation-en lzma 0 B] [Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.88.45)]/usr/bin/lzma: Decoder error
58% [122 Translation-en_NZ lzma 0 B] [Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.88.45)]/usr/bin/lzma: Decoder error
58% [123 Translation-en lzma 0 B] [Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.88.45)]/usr/bin/lzma: Decoder error
58% [124 Translation-en_NZ lzma 0 B] [Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.88.45)]/usr/bin/lzma: Decoder error
58% [125 Translation-en lzma 0 B] [Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.88.45)]/usr/bin/lzma: Decoder error
Fetched 190 kB in 23s (7,917 B/s)                                                  
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_natty_main_binary-i386_Packages
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

last 37 lines only.

I've deleted every thing in the `/var/lib/apt/lists` directory (actually backed it up) and ran `sudo apt-get update` in a terminal. I still getting an error:

```
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_natty_main_binary-i386_Packages E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Comment: @Evan.. have you tried `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf`?

Comment: yes.... not working

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer and accept it. That will help others find it more easily.