# Malformed 3rd word in the Status line error

Tags: 10.10, package-management, updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Problem with MergeList” error when trying to do an update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30072/problem-with-mergelist-error-when-trying-to-do-an-update)

After installing Ubuntu 10.10 I cannot do the update. This is the error message I received:

```
Reading package lists… Error!
E: Malformed 3rd word in the Status line
E: Error occurred while processing lksctp-tools (UsePackage1)
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/dpkg/status
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Anyone, help?