# Package 'vim' has no installation candidate

Tags: installation, package-management

I installed ubuntu inside windows 7 using VMware. I wanted to execute a c program in ubuntu.

when I tried I got like this,

```
b@ubuntu:~/examples$ vim a.c
The program 'vim' can be found in the following packages:
 * vim
 * vim-gnome
 * vim-tiny
 * vim-gtk
 * vim-nox
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected-package>
b@ubuntu:~/examples$ sudo apt-get install vim
[sudo] password for b:
Reading package lists... Done
Building Dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package vim is not available, but is referred to by another Package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obseleted, or 
is only available from another source

E: Package 'vim' has no installation candidate
I tried apt-get install vim

E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13:Permission denied)
E:unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

when I tried to do `su` it asked me for a password . When I typed the root password its not accepting it and says "Authentication Failure"

I could not install the Vim package. Is there any way I can install it? Please suggest me. How do I regain my root paswword.

Comment: paste your /etc/apt/sources.list as it may be corrupted.

Comment: And run `apt-get update` and look for any errors while you're at it.

Comment: @Shane MAdden: After giving the command apt-get update i'm getting the following errors Reading package lists... header E:Encountered a section with no package: header E:Problem with mergelist /var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_maverick_universe_binary-i386_Packages E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix a “Problem with MergeList” or “status file could not be parsed” error when trying to do an update?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30072/)

Answer (score 17):

The same problem occurred with me when I was trying yo install vim on my ubuntu 12.04.
I tried the following and it worked for me: -
`sudo apt-get update`
and after that
`sudo apt-get install vim`
After running these commands, it started working correctly.

Answer (score 3):

When you are prompted for a password after `sudo command`, you have to enter **YOUR** password **not root** password. From the command prompt, the username appears to be `b`, so `b` password should be supplied. Of course, this is valid only if `b` user is allowed to `sudo` (such as being a member of `admin` group in ubuntu).

Comment: I tried as u said but its not taking the password i typed. when i installed ubuntu in vmware all i gave was only one password. and now its not letting me to login as root also. Is there a way to change the root password.

Comment: The root account is disabled by default in Ubuntu.  When you installed you should have created a regular user account (e.g. 'jsmith').  That account will have rights to run programs via sudo (with jsmith's password, not root's).