# Synaptic Manager , Update Manager not working

Tags: updates, synaptic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Problem with MergeList” error when trying to do an update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30072/problem-with-mergelist-error-when-trying-to-do-an-update)

I get this when I update my Ubuntu 12.04

```
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_partner_i18n_Translation-en
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

how to fix this ?