# Parse error on /var/lib/dpkg/status after editing it

Tags: updates, dpkg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix a “Problem with MergeList” error when trying to do an update?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30072/how-do-i-fix-a-problem-with-mergelist-error-when-trying-to-do-an-update)

```
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Translation-en   
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Translation-en    
Fetched 12.7 MB in 7min 31s (28.2 kB/s)                                        
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/dpkg/status
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Thw problem persists even after executing the following commands:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf 
sudo apt-get update
```

Actually I was encountering problems with uninstalling `crossplatformui`.
According to an online sugestion I opened the status file and deleted the part of `crossplatformui`. I have done this before too. But this time after saving the file this error started to show up.