# Failed to load package lists error

Tags: package-management

I get a 'Failed to load package lists' - this didn't work:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
sudo apt-get update
```

Here is a screenshot
 [image: screenshot]

I am using the live cd

Comment: just restart your PC and try again.

Comment: im on the live cd and il loose my things if i do that because i cant install it

Comment: aah never mind i loged out and in and it worked

Comment: This looks like a Live CD, so restarting should fix it. Also, [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/143059/failed-to-load-the-package-list) may help (you may have missed out the `mkdir...` step)

Answer (score 1):

Answered by OP in comments:

> aah never mind i loged out and in and it worked.

However, they were using the Live CD, so this question probably won't apply to anyone.