# How to disable a particular PPA?

Tags: 12.04, updates, ppa, repository

I want to lock updating from the `ppa:ricotz/testing` repository. I don't want to purge it.
I just want to lock the updates from that repository.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and run `software-properties-gtk`.

Click on `Other Software` tab, you'll see that each PPA have two lines here, one for the compiled packages and one for the source, `Uncheck` both lines to disable a PPA.

[image]

Comment: Thanx :) done..

Comment: What's the command line interface to this? I rename the file `*.list` to `*.list.save`.

Answer (score 10):

I would just comment it out in /etc/apt/sources.list like this...

```
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu natty partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu natty partner
```

Comment: oh thats a nice way too.. :) thankyou :)