# Skype doesn't work in Quantal

Tags: 12.10, skype

Since I updated to Quantal Skype doesn't work and I get this error when updating:

```
W:GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F6A071ABEE5D5BA2
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/commercial-ppa-uploaders/skype/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/commercial-ppa-uploaders/skype/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/commercial-ppa-uploaders/skype/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: i think you have problem with internet connection

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-key --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com F6A071ABEE5D5BA2
sudo apt-get update
```

to correct the problem with the `W:GPG error`

If you search , you will not find any address like this `http://archive.canonical.com/commercial-ppa-uploaders/` . The address is wrong or not exist.

If you have added external PPA with this name , disable it or fully remove it. [See here how](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143203/how-to-disable-a-particular-ppa).

Enable the partners repository , [see here how](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14629/how-do-i-enable-the-partner-repository) and then search Ubuntu Software Center to install Skype correctly.