# Difficulties updating Launchpad / Software Updater errors

Tags: updates, launchpad, software-updater

I reference a text file thru out this question. [It can be found here.](http://thieves.cc/Users/PianoMan/ErrorandOtherlink)

Fairly new user, forgive me if this has already been answered. I've done some searching first, but nothing quite matches up. The question boils down into three parts.

I'm running 12.10, and recently Software Updater yelled at me stating it had 26 updates to install. I was updating another program so I chose "remind me later" (or whatever the equivalent was), and then when I went to update a few minutes later, I get the following error (check text file I've linked at the start):

I did some searching here and the closest I found was this answer (check file I've linked at the start). I've used the scripted removal advised by fossfreedom but I'm still getting errors when Software Updater tries to run. I'm only concerned because based on my homework it seems that Launchpad is somewhat important, so I'm concerned unchecking it in Software Sources will keep me from getting future updates on it.

So, the two parts are if I uncheck them in Software Sources, will that be preventing all possible Launchpad updates, will some other "failsafe" still update Launchpad with those items unchecked, or is there something else I should be doing? Thanks in advance for any guidance you can provide.

PS: I apologize that I had to link to a text file with info on the errors and a link to the question I had checked, but I don't have enough rep to have 2 or more URLs, and the errors contain URLs. If there was something I could have done (like linking a question without triggering this, please trout me for it).

Answer (score 0):

That's a simple one.  Quantal doesn't have a compiz ppa.  Just try opening the url in a web browser and lop off parts until you don't get 404s.

Comment: Ok, sounds simple. However, how do I tell Updater to do that? Is that through Software Sources?

Comment: You're not getting it.  The PPA for quantal does not exist.  Remove it from your apt sources http://askubuntu.com/questions/143203/how-to-disable-a-particular-ppa

Comment: OK, sounds great, and thank you. However the condescending "You're not getting it" when I've stated that I'm a beginner and I'm asking for clarification? Check yourself.

Comment: You're not getting it wasn't condescending.  It was an observation of fact.