# Trouble installing VLC

Tags: package-management, software-installation, dependencies, vlc

Whenever I try to install VLC by terminal this shows up.

```
ankit@ankit-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get install vlc
[sudo] password for ankit: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vlc : Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.0.8+git20131023+r618-0~r13~ubuntu13.10.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 2.0.8+git20131023+r618-0~r13~ubuntu13.10.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-pulse (= 2.0.8+git20131023+r618-0~r13~ubuntu13.10.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10.

Please tell me what to do?

When I try to install VLC from software center, this message pops up, `Package dependencies cannot be resolved`.

Comment: Do you have any third party PPAs enabled?

Comment: I don't know. How to check it?

Comment: You have the VLC PPA enabled; you can tell because the package names include `+git[date]` (e.g., `vlc-nox_2.0.8+git20131023+r618-0~r13~ubuntu13.10.1_i386.deb`). I haven't had any problems upgrading my VLC about the time you asked your question, but I'm running 12.04. Try again later.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can i fix this vlc problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/611324/how-can-i-fix-this-vlc-problem)

Answer (score 1):

You have most likely set up a new machine and encrypted your system.

1. Press <kbd>ALT</kbd> and <kbd>F2</kbd> together.
2. Type--> software-properties-gtk and select it.
3. Select the other sources tab.
4. Make sure the boxes that say "canonical partners" and "canonical partners (source code)" are both checked.
5. Agree to the requested update.

You should now be able to install vlc.

Comment: From where do you get, that OP re-installed their system or uses an encrypted system partition?

Comment: Deja vu. I just went through the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

This should fix broken packages or unmet dependencies. Then you can go about installing vlc.

Comment: Did it. But it didn't help. The problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have Third party PPAs enabled. Disable them. See this question

- [How to disable a particular PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143203/how-to-disable-a-particular-ppa)

Now refresh your package list with `sudo apt-get update` and do `sudo apt-get install -f` to solve the problem.

Comment: If your answer is essentially a referral to another question, it would be better to flag this question as a duplicate of the other.

Comment: @David Foerster: Although the answer might be the same, the question is clearly not. Flagging a question as duplicate should only be done if **the question** is a duplicate, not if the answer is a duplicate. It is, however advisable to put the relevant info in the answer itself as registered user said.

Comment: @Anwar Shah: It is advisable to put the relevant information in your answer itself. Also please advise on what ppa he should remove.

Comment: Well, this is not same answer either. I was referring to answer for as an step for this. The answer is disabling ppa, refreshing and using the last command. @DavidFoerster