# how can i fix this vlc problem

Tags: vlc

I use ubuntu 14.04LTS, when I type in:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

I receive this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
   vlc : Depends: vlc-nox (= 3.0.0~~git20150319+r59816+33~ubuntu14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: libavcodec55 (>= 6:9.1-1) but it is not installable or
            libavcodec-extra-55 (>= 6:10~~git20131218.b3189af~ubuntu14.04.1) but it is not installable
   Depends: libavutil53 (>= 6:9.1-1) but it is not installable
   Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 3.0.0~~git20150319+r59816+33~ubuntu14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
   Recommends: vlc-plugin-samba (= 3.0.0~~git20150319+r59816+33~ubuntu14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: read this article http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies

Comment: give me the outputs for `apt-cache policy vlc-nox` and `apt-cache policy libavcodec-extra-54` and **don't** post them as an answer.

Comment: hhhh ok one sec it worked but i will give it any way
i think i really stared to bother u sorry

Comment: nothing at all...

Comment: apt-cache policy vlc-nox
    vlc-nox:
  Installed: 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1
  Candidate: 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1 0
        500 http://tn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.1.2-2build2 0
        500 http://tn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe i386 Packages

Comment: this is the command you have to run and the second one just run them both and paste them to pastebin.com and post a link here

Comment: apt-cache policy libavcodec-extra-54
    libavcodec-extra-54:
  Installed: 6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1+fdkaac
  Candidate: 6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1+fdkaac
  Version table:
 *** 6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1+fdkaac 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 0
        500 http://tn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/universe i386 Packages
     6:9.11-2ubuntu2 0
        500 http://tn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe i386 Packages

Comment: ok so did you manage to install vlc?

Comment: hhh yeah sorry for anooying again
i just deleted some ppa and it's done

Comment: if everything is fine now then great!

Comment: i just wanted to update the vlc version from 2.1.6 to 2.2.1 but this happened :P

Comment: current stable vlc package is 2.2.0 if you want it I can guide you through adding that to my question so you can except it to clear this mess

Comment: yes plz and what i do again :P ??

Comment: so how can you guide me plz ??

Comment: if that solves your issue then we came to a solution, you can accept the answer if that what you wanted.

Comment: You're welcome! don't forget to click on a grey tick (to accept) on the left side of the answer under votes counter.

Comment: `apt-get update`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your issue you had to disable unstable ppa/repos as instructed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Then open a terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge vlc-nox
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

If you want to use more fresh version of VLC media player rather than in official Ubuntu repos, you can use Videolan official stable-daily PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/stable-daily
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

**Addition:**

Just for the others who face an issue upgrading vlc to 2.2.0 on 14.04LTS even occured to me with `ppa:videolan/stable-daily` it still had 2.1.6 version installed. To upgrade it to 2.2.0 version add this `trusty-media` PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall vlc
```

**P.S.**

Do remember this ppa contains also other media updates to see what exactly will be changed if you run an upgrade check with this command:

```
cat /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_mc3man_trusty-media_*_Packages | grep "Package:" | sort | uniq
```

If you want to purge it after you have installed vlc then:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: You might want to add `sudo dpkg --configure -a`.

Comment: if that won't work yes, but I had the same issue a couple of days ago after adding a ppa and that's what I did. I had to purge vlc-nox nothing else worked. :)

Comment: i deleted some old ppa in the software center and then tryed it it worked :P

Comment: if it worked, I'm glad I could help you.

Comment: the Videolan official stable-daily PPA didn't work i am still in version 2.1.6

Comment: did you run `apt-get update` and then run `upgrade`? if you do everything according to my answer you cannot be on 2.1.6 version after you add ppa and run an update you can check it with `apt-cache policy vlc`

Comment: yes nothing happened

Comment: give me the output of `apt-cache policy vlc`

Comment: vlc:
  Installed: 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1
  Candidate: 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1 0
        500 http://tn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.1.4+git20150226+r54594+19+11~ubuntu14.04.1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
     2.1.2-2build2 0
        500 http://tn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe i386 Packages

Comment: did you enable multiverse/universe repos? as instructed in my answer with marked link `here`?

Comment: yes i did  in the software centre

Comment: well check it this way what you get as a result is recommended stable vlc package for your distro but you can install unstable or the latest using this [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/105587/how-to-update-vlc-to-the-latest-version)

Comment: hhh nothing still the same

Comment: well it s ok if it doesn't want to update at least it work maybe it will update by itself with software updater :P
thnx any way u definitely teached me a lot
ubuntu is definitely better than windows

Comment: well it won't be the same if you add for example this ppa `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media` you will have vlc 2.2.0 version to do so after adding it run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install --reinstall vlc` then purge that ppa if you don't want it `sudo ppa-purge ppa:mc3man/trusty-media` because it contains lots of media stuff that be upgraded if you don't want it then just purge it.

Comment: i think that the one that broken it in the first place but if u said it i will try it again

Comment: I'm using it in my system :) if you run an `upgrade` it will cause a change to the system only then and again it depends on you, you can just run `dist-upgrade` and it'll be fine.

Comment: The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Remove the following packages:                          
1)     gstreamer1.0-libav                                    
2)     libvlc5 
3)     vlc
4)     vlc-nox
5)     vlc-plugin-notify
6)     vlc-plugin-pulse
     Keep the following packages at their current version:   
7)     libavcodec54 [Not Installed]                          
8)     libvlccore7 [Not Installed]
     Leave the following dependencies unresolved:            
9)     ubuntu-restricted-addons recommends gstreamer1.0-libav
 

what do i do ??

Comment: it's done thnx alot

Comment: you're welcome! after adding ppa you do as instructed in my answer when smth is stuck.

Comment: thnx alot
can you tell me plz what's the different between purge and remove ??

Comment: purge will remove configuration also.

Comment: than purge is better :P
thnx again u really helped alot 
i hope one day i can help ubuntu users like u too :P
have a great day

Comment: one more thing :P 
how can  i type     code    in askubuntu or forumubuntu

Comment: this talk is off-topic in this question there's the `help` tab next to your profile where you can take a tour and learn more how Ask Ubuntu works.