# VLC media player Installing error

Tags: apt, dependencies, vlc

I'm totally new to Ubuntu, I have version 14.04, and when I go to Software Centre to install VLC Media Player it gives an error: "Package dependencies cant be solved" The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
vlc: Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1) but 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1 is to be installed
     Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.6 is to be installed
     Depends: libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1) but 2.5.2-1ubuntu2.4 is to be installed
     Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.9-20140406-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
     Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
     Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
     Depends: libsdl-image1.2 (>= 1.2.10) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: libsdl1.2debian (>= 1.2.11) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) but 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 is to be installed
     Depends: libtar0 but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: libva-x11-1 (> 1.3.0~) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: libva1 (> 1.3.0~) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: libxcb-composite0 but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: libxcb-xv0 (>= 1.2) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.3.3) but 1:1.2.8.dfsg-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
```

I tried `sudo apt-get update` but still same error

Comment: you can use [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/611324/how-can-i-fix-this-vlc-problem/611328#611328) if you still didn't solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening a Terminal window and run these commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge vlc
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey friend try following Command

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

It will remove the dependency problem And then go to software center nad type vlc in searh box and then install it.

If you want to install by command line then Simply type

```
sudo apt-get install vlc* -y
```

Comment: this will not solve the problem.