# Ubuntu 14.04, Rhythmbox, missing gstreamer1.0-libav (i386) plugin dependencies

Tags: 14.04, sound, dependencies, rhythmbox, gstreamer

I've recently updated Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 (64 bit version).

The problem that I've noticed is that Rhythmbox
cannot play ALAC (m4a) files. Also, when I run some radio stations,
the systems complains that I don't have Windows Media Audio 8
decoder.

Whenever I start the playback the Ubutnu suggest to install
gstreamer1.0-libav (i386) plugin, and then
dumps an error message saying:

```
gstreamer1.0-libav:i386: Depends: libavcodec-extra-54 (>= 6:9.13) but 6:9.16-0ubuntu0.14.04.1+fdkaac is to be installed
                     Depends: libavformat54 (>= 6:9.1-1) but 6:9.16-0ubuntu0.14.04.1+fdkaac is to be installed
                     Depends: libavutil52 (>= 6:9.1-1) but 6:9.16-0ubuntu0.14.04.1+fdkaac is to be installed
                     Depends: libc6 (>= 2.7) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.3 is to be installed
                     Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.37.3) but 2.40.0-2 is to be installed
```

Now I have installed the gstreamer1.0-libav, but apparently
Rhythmbox is not satisfied with that version.

I've already installed ubuntu-restricted-extras and gstreamer0.1-ffmpeg.

I would like to provide more information but I don't know what's relevant.
Also, I don't know how to interpret this error message.

Thank you for help.

Comment: Looks like you have some PPAs there. Try disabling them, then reloading package info.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? I'm a bit confused about how to disable them and which ones. Thanks.

Comment: Disabling PPAs is easy, and has been answered [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/143203/how-to-disable-a-particular-ppa) [before](http://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed). As for figuring out which, look at the output of `apt-cache search libavcodec-extra-54` to see where it comes from.

Comment: Here is the answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/527127/gstreamer1-0-libav-package-dependencies-cannot-be-resolved