# "gstreamer1.0-libav" Package dependencies cannot be resolved

Tags: 14.04, codecs, gstreamer

I am in Ubuntu 14.04 amd64, I have met all updates available, but also I am getting these errors in media codecs. First I got this error:

```
    gstreamer1.0-libav:i386: Depends: libavcodec-extra-54 (>= 6:9.13) but 6:9.16-0ubuntu0.14.04.1+fdkaac is to be installed
                 Depends: libavformat54 (>= 6:9.1-1) but 6:9.16-0ubuntu0.14.04.1+fdkaac is to be installed
                 Depends: libavutil52 (>= 6:9.1-1) but 6:9.16-0ubuntu0.14.04.1+fdkaac is to be installed
                 Depends: libc6 (>= 2.7) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.3 is to be installed
                 Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.37.3) but 2.40.0-2 is to be installed
```

After getting this error I tried to install those libraries, i then did

```
    sudo apt-get install libavcodec-extra-54
```

That went good, and i could download that package. But any other packages were not installed, terminal said they were already installed.

But again I am getting this error.

```
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
   libavcodec54:
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try the following:

`sudo apt-get install libopus0`

Then:

`sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-liba`

According to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/502207/ubuntu-14-04-problem-with-gstreamer1-0-libav) it should work. It did for him.

Unfortunately I do not find any reason why it works or why libavcodec54 do not.

Reference

1. [ubuntu 14.04 problem with gstreamer1.0-libav](https://askubuntu.com/questions/502207/ubuntu-14-04-problem-with-gstreamer1-0-libav)