# Packages Broken not able to Play Videos

Tags: package-management, video, dependencies, gstreamer

Hi not able to play videos getting and unable to install video players too

```
gstreamer1.0-libav : Depends: libavcodec54 (>= 6:9.1-1) but it is not going to be installed or
                               libavcodec-extra-54 (>= 6:9.13) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libavformat54 (>= 6:9.1-1) but it is not going to be installed
 gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad : Depends: libchromaprint0 (>= 0.2) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libopencv-contrib2.4 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libopencv-highgui2.4 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libopencv-legacy2.4 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libopencv-objdetect2.4 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libopus0 (>= 1.0.3) but it is not going to be installed

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Please help

Comment: Look at this question too: http://askubuntu.com/questions/527127/gstreamer1-0-libav-package-dependencies-cannot-be-resolved

Answer (score 0):

I Just had to install the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get install libopus0 gstreamer1.0-liba
```

And it is done.

Source: [ubuntu 14.04 problem with gstreamer1.0-libav](https://askubuntu.com/questions/502207/ubuntu-14-04-problem-with-gstreamer1-0-libav)