# apt-file update

Tags: apt, apt-file

When I try and update my files using the command apt-file update in the terminal it starts to do so, until I get to a certain point then I get the following message:

```
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 401 Authorization Required
Download of https://private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/vkaudiosaver/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Contents-amd64.gz failed
Command exited with code 22
```

Any knowledge on how to get this to finish the update?
Or how would I get the Authorization required to finish my up date?

Comment: **sudo** apt-file update?

Comment: I attempted this, I thought the same thing that it may be the issue, but I got the same error, I can manage to download the first file, and a few after that, some are up to date, it is just the one spot mentioned above that gives me the error being

curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 401 Authorization Required Download of https://private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/vkaudiosaver/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Contents-amd64.gz failed Command exited with code 22

Comment: Are you sure that you have installed "apt-file"?

**sudo apt-get install apt-file**

Comment: It's a private PPA. Ask whoever maintains it for authorization.

Comment: I had to do that first before I tried the initial update, I re ran the command just now and it stated it was already done.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because the PPA is a private (commmercial) PPA that requires authorization to visit. To cross check try to access [the PPA](https://private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/vkaudiosaver/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Contents-amd64.gz) from a browser.

To get pass it, either [disable the PPA](https://askubuntu.com/q/143203/216503) or get proper authentication token.

Comment: disabling the PPA worked, as it was the only thing causing the issue

Comment: @LeoTobias Glad it worked..If you want any package from that PPA try to get proper authentication from the maintainer though..

Comment: Yes I will have to see what I can do to find out the maintainer.

Comment: How would I get a proper authorization token?

Comment: @sschuberth you need to contact the PPA maintainer..see the relevant launchpad page for details..

Comment: I am the PPA maintainer, and still I cannot figure out how to make apt-get authenticate against the private PPA. The concrete situation is: I'm maintaining a private PPA in a LaunchPad team that I'm part of. When trying to access the PPA via HTTP I'm prompted for my username and a token, but I have to idea where to get that token from, and I also do not find any documentation related to that. Would you have a link to the documentation?