# Ubuntu 17.10 apt-get update giving 404 NOT FOUND error for repository

Tags: apt, 17.10, repository

When I am trying to update my Ubuntu 17.10 system with sudo apt-get update I am receiving the following error for one of the repositories:

```
    Err:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make/ubuntu artful Release                                                       
    404  Not Found
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make/ubuntu artful Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
```

I am not able to trace the repository in the `/etc/apt/sources.list` or `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` 
This issue has been observed very recently. Can anybody tell me how to find this repository and disable or remove it? Because of this error I am not able to update my system. Thanks

Comment: That error does not stop you from updating your system, just run `sudo apt upgrade`. To disable see https://askubuntu.com/questions/143203/how-to-disable-a-particular-ppa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mentioned repository does not have any packages for artful (17.10), which causes the 404. You have to remove it from your configuration.

You should either be able to do that from the Software & Updates settings GUI, or find the sources list file mentioning it and remove or comment that line.

As you say you have trouble locating it, try:

```
grep -r --include "*.list" "^deb" /etc/apt/sources.list* | grep "ubuntu-make"
```

That should show you the file name, line number and content of the line configuring this PPA.

Comment: @SabyasachiMitra if you still need [`ubuntu-make`](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make) - you can install it from other PPA (`ppa:lyzardking/ubuntu-make`).