# Ubuntu Software Centre not opening

Tags: updates, software-center, software-sources, synaptics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix a “Problem with MergeList” error when trying to do an update?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30072/how-do-i-fix-a-problem-with-mergelist-error-when-trying-to-do-an-update)

While trying to install Ubuntu restricted extras package from the ubuntu software-center, it suddenly crashed. and after typing "software-center" in terminal, it is showing:

```
2012-08-24 20:55:20,221 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
2012-08-24 20:55:20,327 - softwarecenter.db.database - INFO - open() database: path=None use_axi=True use_agent=True
2012-08-24 20:55:20,362 - softwarecenter.db.database - ERROR - failed to add apt-xapian-index
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/database.py", line 179, in _get_new_xapiandb
    softwarecenter.paths.APT_XAPIAN_INDEX_DB_PATH)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xapian/__init__.py", line 3666, in __init__
    _xapian.Database_swiginit(self,_xapian.new_Database(*args))
DatabaseOpeningError: Couldn't stat '/var/lib/apt-xapian-index/index' (No such file or directory)
2012-08-24 20:55:21,118 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - Could not get usefulness from server, no username in config file
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/pkginfo_impl/aptcache.py", line 242, in open
    self._cache = apt.Cache(GtkMainIterationProgress())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 102, in __init__
    self.open(progress)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 145, in open
    self._cache = apt_pkg.Cache(progress)
SystemError: E:Encountered a section with no Package: header, E:Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-updates_main_binary-i386_Packages, E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
2012-08-24 20:55:23,234 - softwarecenter.db.categories - WARNING - sort by cataloged time requested but your a-x-i does not seem to support that yet
2012-08-24 20:55:24,252 - softwarecenter.db.categories - WARNING - sort by cataloged time requested but your a-x-i does not seem to support that yet
2012-08-24 20:55:24,375 - softwarecenter.db.categories - WARNING - sort by cataloged time requested but your a-x-i does not seem to support that yet
2012-08-24 20:55:24,445 - softwarecenter.db.categories - WARNING - sort by cataloged time requested but your a-x-i does not seem to support that yet
2012-08-24 20:55:24,511 - softwarecenter.db.categories - WARNING - sort by cataloged time requested but your a-x-i does not seem to support that yet
2012-08-24 20:55:24,792 - softwarecenter.db.enquire - ERROR - _get_estimate_nr_apps_and_nr_pkgs failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/enquire.py", line 115, in _get_estimate_nr_apps_and_nr_pkgs
    tmp_matches = enquire.get_mset(0, len(self.db), None, xfilter)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/appfilter.py", line 89, in __call__
    if (not pkgname in self.cache and
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/pkginfo_impl/aptcache.py", line 262, in __contains__
    return self._cache.__contains__(k)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__contains__'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 176, in <module>
    app.run(args)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 1341, in run
    self.show_available_packages(args)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 1271, in show_available_packages
    self.view_manager.set_active_view(ViewPages.AVAILABLE)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/session/viewmanager.py", line 149, in set_active_view
    view_widget.init_view()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/panes/availablepane.py", line 165, in init_view
    self.apps_filter)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/catview_gtk.py", line 240, in __init__
    self.build(desktopdir)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/catview_gtk.py", line 491, in build
    self._build_homepage_view()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/catview_gtk.py", line 267, in _build_homepage_view
    self._append_top_rated()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/catview_gtk.py", line 404, in _append_top_rated
    top_rated_cat = self._update_top_rated_content()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/catview_gtk.py", line 391, in _update_top_rated_content
    docs = top_rated_cat.get_documents(self.db)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/categories.py", line 124, in get_documents
    nonblocking_load=False)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/enquire.py", line 317, in set_query
    self._blocking_perform_search()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/enquire.py", line 212, in _blocking_perform_search
    matches = enquire.get_mset(0, self.limit, None, xfilter)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/appfilter.py", line 89, in __call__
    if (not pkgname in self.cache and
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/pkginfo_impl/aptcache.py", line 262, in __contains__
    return self._cache.__contains__(k)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__contains__'
```

I am a beginner and don't know what to do about it.