# error opening cache

Tags: 12.04, package-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix a “Problem with MergeList” error when trying to do an update?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30072/how-do-i-fix-a-problem-with-mergelist-error-when-trying-to-do-an-update)

I have been reviving the following error today, because of this I cannot install any programs or update or any thing.

```
    W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 464AD83D4631BBEA Launchpad equinoxart
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_tiheum_equinox_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_binary-i386_Packages
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

This code is from running `apt-get update`.

I also read that this could be because of un-met dependences how would I resolve this ?