# Canno't open ubuntu software center and synaptic package manager

Tags: software-center, synaptics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix a “Problem with MergeList” error when trying to do an update?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30072/how-do-i-fix-a-problem-with-mergelist-error-when-trying-to-do-an-update)

```
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_quantal_partner_i18n_Translation-en%5fUS
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
E: _cache->open() failed, please report.
```

Can anyone solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running these commands in the terminal

> sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
>
> sudo apt-get update