# Reporting an error from an undetermined package

Tags: package-management, error-handling

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and regularly get errors related to printing on an HP750 PSC.

I am asked to accept filing a report, which I do and then the message returned is

```
Could not determine package or source package name.
```

Does this mean that there are persistent problems that cannot be reported back, and are therefore not being addressed?

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow these steps, if you have network connection.

> [How do I fix a "Problem with MergeList" or "status file could not be parsed" error when trying to do an update?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30072/problem-with-mergelist-error-with-update-manager)
>   They seem to be corrupt or invalid MergeList.

To make it more safer, I would make a full copy of

Code:

> /var/lib/apt/lists/*
>   before to delete it.