# Problem with apt-get update on ubuntu server

Tags: 12.04, server

I have ubuntu 32 bit 12.04 server edition but i am having issues with apt-get updating.

The server is able to ping the outside world (both `8.8.8.8` and `www.google.com`) but when I attempt to `sudo apt-get update` the first bit works but then I get this:

[image]

If i attempt to check or autoclean with:

```
sudo apt-get check
```

I get this:

[image]

I have tried the fix detailed here:

[How do I fix a "Problem with MergeList" or "status file could not be parsed" error when trying to do an update?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30072/how-do-i-fix-a-problem-with-mergelist-error-when-trying-to-do-an-update)

But it does not work, the same thing occurs again. Any suggestions?

PS.  The server is a fresh install, no external programs have been added.

**EDIT:** We have tried using different sources, both aarnet and au.archive sources were tried.

Comment: choosing different sources caused this problem.

Comment: @K.KPatel Unfortunately not, we used the original source and tried several others as well, the actual answer is the one i have posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer is:

Watch out for university networks. It required a log in form a web browser to enable that machine to access certain parts of the Internet. To get around it we had to log into the university network using a live usb version of ubuntu desktop. Then the update went through just fine.

Damn networks !!

Comment: Why did you log in from the live CD instead of from the installed system?

Comment: @jdthood there is no browser on ubuntu server, not sure how you can access the login page from cmd prompt. So we used the live CD for the ubuntu desktop version.

Comment: Well, you could use lynx. I just asked because I wanted to know if you had run into some technical problem connecting to the login page from the installed system.

Comment: How would i use lynx to connect to a website, be redirected to the university log in page and then enter password and username information? Do you want to add that as an answer and i will upvote and mark as correct

Comment: Hmm, well on second thought you couldn't use lynx since it's not installed by default, and your problem was that you couldn't connect to repository servers.  :)

Comment: hahaha, yeah that will be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try using another mirror. I assume you have Internet connectivity. Open Ubuntu Software Center | Edit | Software Sources and change "Download from" to something else. Then in a terminal run "sudo apt-get update".

Comment: where can i find different mirrors?

Comment: We have tried, As now noted in the question, any other suggestions?