# Bug 12.10. No reply to the bug report or alternative to submit the report or bug not answered

Tags: bug-reporting, debugging

First, I am new to Ubuntu, and then I was getting a recurring error: window titled `"crash report"` (it's contents are as below). There is Stop sign being shown at the top next to the battery indicator. Then I can't open the software updates and I'm not able to get updates via terminal.I have tried the 'package manager troubleshooting' help but I don't know how exactly it works and hence I am not able to do anything.

The error looks like this:

```
Executable Path
/usr/lib/evolution/evolution-calender-factory
Problem Type
 crash
Architecture 
 Amd64
Core Dump
 (binary data)
Crash Counter
 1
Date
 Fri , Dec 21...
Disassembly
```

*there is a lot description under this and difficult to write but it has something like*

```
divl
mov
mov
test 
jne 
jmpg
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have submitted the crash report, you have little options but wait for the developers to read and solve it. They are usually busy folks, but the bug will get a response, either from a real developer or from a robot processing it.

Note that the more likely answer is that the bug is a duplicate.

If you don't want to wait for a solution, you can only try to solve it yourself (if you have enough knowledge) or try to get someone with the knowledge to solve it (either paying or asking nicely **once**).

If you want better care you can always opt for [pay support](http://www.canonical.com/enterprise-services/ubuntu-advantage/support), but it doesn't come cheap. Please check what some option covers before buying it. If you want a developer ready to solve your bugs are soon as you find them, you will need to pay thousand of dollars/year.

Comment: alright but is there any way to check whether the bug has really been reported or not. I don't have the knowledge so I can't really handle this.Regarding paying someone I really don't think I can do that.Worst case I have to switch back to windows.

Comment: You can search launchpad for the bug. See http://asku buntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug. In your case the answer is yes, this bug is reported. But it's not related to the problem with Software Manager. This could be related to http://askubuntu.com/questions/30072/how-do-i-fix-a-problem-with-mergelist-error-when-trying-to-do-an-update

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have tried looking at the link before but I think I don't have the know how of the terminal and I am not able to use it to solve my problem.Hence I will wait for the response.

Comment: Then you should probably add a comment to that question, your question here is different, it's about what to do when a bug is not answered. You can also make a new question, but link the other and make clear that you want a GUI answer, if you didn't it will be closed as duplicated. But the truth is that I don't expect that there is a non-comand line answer.

Answer (score 0):

Evolution-calender-factory actually is quite buggy, so you are not the only one getting this.

Do you use evolution (a mail client)? If not, feel free to do:

> sudo apt-get purge evolution-data-server evolution evolution-indicator evolution-plugins

After the purge, check whether you can run

> sudo apt-get update

Oh, by the way, that is a free command :)

I don't think this is a case where paid help is required.

Comment: "E: Invalid record in the preferences file /etc/apt/preferences, no Package header". I tried the commands you posted
This is the error I get if I try to install anything via terminal.Though I get the updates but still situation persists and software center doesn't open.Thanks for the anyways ..