# Cant open softwarer center

Tags: software-center

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix a “Problem with MergeList” error when trying to do an update?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30072/how-do-i-fix-a-problem-with-mergelist-error-when-trying-to-do-an-update)

I click on software center and it opens and closes so i tried to reinstall it in terminal and i get this error how do i fix this ?

```
Reading package lists... Error!  
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header  
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_quantal-security_universe_binary-i386_Packages  
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a corrupt file. Fortunately it can be thrown away and reloaded with  afew simple commands:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_quantal-security_universe_binary-i386_Packages
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: i cant remove that file with that command what can i do ?

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: Reading package lists... Error!
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_quantal-security_multiverse_i18n_Translation-en
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.

Comment: That's not a possible error for `sudo rm ...` Looks like the rm worked, but you have more lists that need to be removed. Try this: `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*Packages` and then `sudo apt-get update.