# Update manager error: "The package lists or status file could not be opened or read"

Tags: update-manager

In Ubuntu 12.04, update manager says:

> E: Read error - read (5: Input / output error), E: The package lists
>   or status file could not be opened or read, meaning that your
>   installed packages have unresolved dependencies.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I fix a "Problem with MergeList" or "status file could not be parsed" error when trying to do an update?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/30072/how-do-i-fix-a-problem-with-mergelist-or-status-file-could-not-be-parsed-err)

Comment: @JorgeCastro That's not an I/O error as this is. They're superficially similar, but are you sure this is really a duplicate of that?

Comment: I'm not sure until the OP tries the solution and sees if it works.