# Apt-get update errors (can't read the package lists)

Tags: 12.10, apt, updates

After running the an update from the `update-manager` I tried to install chromium:

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

And I got the following error ([full output from `sudo apt-get update' on Ubuntu Pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5576692/)):

```
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Malformed 2nd word in the Status line
E: Error occurred while processing curl (UsePackage3)
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/dpkg/status
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Working from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30072/how-do-i-fix-a-problem-with-mergelist-or-status-file-could-not-be-parsed-err) I guessed there was something wrong with my MergeList. So per the top answer, I removed the Merge List.

```
 sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
```

Then I attempted an update.

```
 sudo apt-get update
```

And got the same set of error messages.

My next thought was that one of the repos I had added was faulty in some manner. `/etc/apt/sources.list` was full on Canonical sources and nothing else. `etc/apt/sources.list.d` had a few 3rd party sources I had added (namely `heroku` and Chris Lea's `node.js`). Just in case I cleared out that directory with `sudo rm *`. Then deleted the MergeList, and attempted an update. Same error.

What might be causing this set of errors and how do I correct it?

Comment: Please, upload the output that you get after do `sudo apt-get update` in paste.ubuntu.com and link it in your question editing it. Also, have you read [the comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/30072/how-do-i-fix-a-problem-with-mergelist-or-status-file-could-not-be-parsed-err#comment231426_30199) of that answer?

Comment: output from `sudo apt-get update` [is on paste.ubuntu.com](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5576692/). As for [the comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/30072/how-do-i-fix-a-problem-with-mergelist-or-status-file-could-not-be-parsed-err#comment231426_30199) I've deleted the MergeList at least dozen times at this point.

Comment: Try with [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/136403/62483), if you didn't yet.

Comment: yes yes, you hadn't posted your comment when I said that but somehow we commented at the same time :D. I have to remove it I guess.

Comment: Replacing status with status-old did the job. Thanks to both of you.  One last etiquette question though: Should I close this question or answer it myself with a link to the correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that `/var/lib/dpkg/status` got corrupted. The solution was to restore from `/var/lib/dpkg/status-old`.  Before you do that though, [read the full answer.](https://askubuntu.com/a/136403/71592)

Thanks to Lucio and Soroosh129 for pointing me to the solution.