# E: Encountered a section with no Package: header

Tags: package-management, localrepository

After making index for my local repository, I get this error while updating.

```
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/_home_soroush_repository_dists_precise_local_binary-amd64_Packages
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
E: _cache->open() failed, please report.
```

Then no package manager works. I know that there is a problem with index file generated by `dpkg-scan-packages` but can't find it.

I maintain my repo using this script and it worked properly for a long time:

```
#!/bin/bash
for dist in "precise" #"oneiric"
do
    for component in "local"
    do
        for architecture in "amd64" # "i386" "all" 
        do
            echo "Generating package index for $dist $component $architecture..." 
            dpkg-scanpackages -a $architecture pool/local /dev/null | gzip -9c > dists/$dist/local/binary-$architecture/Packages
        done
    echo "Generating source index for $dist $component $architecture..." 
    dpkg-scansources pool/local > dists/$dist/local/sources/Sources
    done
done
```

My question is how can I find which package is causing problem in index file? There should be some sort of parser for that...

Comment: Similar question for those that are seeing the same sort of error but not using a local repository: http://askubuntu.com/questions/30072/how-do-i-fix-a-problem-with-mergelist-or-status-file-could-not-be-parsed-err?lq=1

Answer (score 3):

So, this is a little weird I'm answering my own question! :D

This may help someone out there. I found that the only problem is file name of generated index. It should end up with .gz extension. Previously `Packages` was acceptable for `dpkg` now he expects `Packages.gz`. This is a new rule, meanwhile, someone in debian team decided it to be like this! I updated my local repo generator script and everything works file now.

Comment: how did you update?

Comment: @MildFuzz `dpkg-scanpackages -a $architecture pool/local | gzip -9c > dists/$dist/local/binary-$architecture/Packages.gz`