# UpdateManager Error

Tags: apt, updates

I have this icon in my desktop (Sorry, I am not allowed to post images)

And here I transcribe the information about the error in update Manager.

```
E: Encountered a package with no header 
E:Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists es.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_i18n_Translation-en
E:Package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

How can I solve this issue? Should I do something or take it easy until it gets fixed by itself?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These commands should solve your issue:

Remove the merge list by opening up a terminal (shortcut: press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to launch) and run this command:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
```

Enter the root password if prompted. And then, generate a new one by running up an update:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/30199/179042