# Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/ca.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_multiverse_i18n_Translation-en

Tags: updates, update-manager

> Could not initialize the package information
>       An unresolvable problem occurred while initializing the package information.
>       Please report this bug against the 'update-manager' package and include the following error message:
>
> ```
> E:Encountered a section with no Package: header, 
> E:Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/ca.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_multiverse_i18n_Translation-en,
> E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.'
> ```

This is the message I receive when i click the top left corner of my screen and click the Software Updater.

What should I do?

Comment: Duplicated http://askubuntu.com/q/30072/62483

Answer (score 0):

Open up your terminal and...

First do the following:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
```

Then:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade
```