# Ignoring specific unmet dependencies with aptitude?

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, aptitude

This is my situation: I've installed a program called `ipe` "forcably" through a deb package; the reason for this is that `ipe` depends on `texlive-latex-base`, however, I already maintain a separate install of `latex` via `tlmgr`. There is no problem with that kind of install of `ipe`, however, as long as I remember to run it from a terminal, which suits me fine.

The problem is that that broken dependency now doesn't allow me to install packages which are completely unrelated - in this case, dropbox:

```
$ sudo apt-get install dropbox
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ipe : Depends: texlive-latex-base but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Now, if I try `-f install`, that will try to fix the `ipe` install, which is what I do *not* want.

It turns out, `aptitude` looks like it could offer a way to ignore/skip over this dependency:

```
$ sudo aptitude install dropbox
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dropbox 
The following partially installed packages will be configured:
  ipe{b} 
0 packages upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 93,0 kB of archives. After unpacking 410 kB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  ipe: Depends: texlive-latex-base but it is not going to be installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Remove the following packages:
1)     ipe                         



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] 1
Action "1": Removing ipe

Package: ipe
State: unpacked
Automatically installed: no
Version: 7.0.10-2
Priority: optional
...

This action was selected because ipe depends upon texlive-latex-base.

Enter "r 1" to prevent this action from appearing in new solutions.
Enter "a 1" to require that new solutions include this action if possible.

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] r 1
Rejecting the removal of ipe
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Remove the following packages:
1) R   ipe                         



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] y
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dropbox 
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  ipe{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 1 newly installed, 1 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 93,0 kB of archives. After unpacking 5.034 kB will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] n
Abort.
```

The weird thing is: even if I specify `r 1` - and the program actually confirms that with "`Rejecting the removal of ipe`" - I *still* get "`The following packages will be REMOVED`" in the end, which is I what I specifically do *not* want to do? (Btw, I've also tried `a 1`, and the end results are completely the same, "... will be REMOVED", although that is the action I'd expect for that choice).

Where am I going wrong? Am I misunderstanding what they mean by "new solutions"? And is there a way to have the apt/aptitude system know, that I'd rather it ignores the unmet dependencies of (in this case) `ipe`?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Ok, as noted below, the "rejecting the removal..." thing in `aptitude` does not work - this is what did manage to work for me, though...

While looking for, say, `Package: ipe`, one may hit files such as:

```
$ grep -r 'Package: ipe' /var/lib/apt/lists/
...
/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_natty_universe_binary-i386_Packages:Package: ipe
...
/var/lib/apt/lists/old-releases.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_natty_universe_binary-i386_Packages:Package: ipe
...
```

... however, these are not right - apparently, the runtime information for `apt-get` etc. is stored in `/var/lib/dpkg/status` ( via [How do I fix a "Problem with MergeList" or "status file could not be parsed" error when trying to do an update?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30072/how-do-i-fix-a-problem-with-mergelist-or-status-file-could-not-be-parsed-err/136403#136403) ).

So, I opened that file via `sudo nano /var/lib/dpkg/status`, and looked up "Package: ipe", and then tried to comment the `texlive-latex-base` portion of "Depends:" - first by putting it in a separate line, at commenting it with a number sign/hash `#`. Note that this does *not* work - first you'll get errors like:

```
dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 8140 package 'ipe':
 field name `#,' must be followed by colon
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

... then if you try to add that colon, as in `#:`, you'll get:

```
dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 8141 package 'ipe':
 user-defined field name `#' too short
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Apparently, these files do not use comments; and they seem to be documented in [Debian Policy Manual - Control files and their fields](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html). Then I found:

[#353040 - [DPKG-DEB] don't be so noisy about user defined fields in DEBIAN/control - Debian Bug report logs](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=353040)

> The right way to include a field in the .deb is to use
>   fields named "XB-*".

... so, basically, instead of using a comment character to "comment out" - I just used an user-defined field, instead, which I arbitrarily called `XB-Ignore:`; so that portion of `/var/lib/dpkg/status` ended up looking like this:

```
Package: ipe
...
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4), libcairo2 (>= 1.2.4), libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1), libipe7.0.10, liblua5.1-0, libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.6.$
XB-Ignore: , texlive-latex-base, gsfonts
...
```

With this change saved, I could perform the install using `apt-get` directly, without a problem:

```
$ sudo apt-get install dropbox
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  python-gpgme
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dropbox
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/93,0 kB of archives.
After this operation, 410 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously deselected package dropbox.
...
Setting up dropbox (1.6.1) ...
Processing triggers for menu ...
```

I'll just note that `/var/lib/dpkg/status` is not a persistant file - in fact, right after the `apt-get install`, if you check the file again, `Depends:` and `XB-Ignore:` will no longer be on neighboring lines (as they were originally, as shown on the snippet above)!

---

While the question on ignoring the unmet dependency is <s>still open</s> noted above - it turns out I *did* misinterpret what these "new solutions" are: it is the choices you're offered by `aptitude` if you answer "no" to the "Accept this solution?" question:

```
...
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  ipe: Depends: texlive-latex-base but it is not going to be installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Remove the following packages:
1)     ipe                         


Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] r 1
Rejecting the removal of ipe
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Remove the following packages:
1) R   ipe                         


Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] n                      # <==== here not accepting above solution
The following actions will resolve these dependencies: # <==== new solution offered here:

      Install the following packages:           
1)      lmodern [2.004.1-3 (natty)]             
2)      luatex [0.65.0-1ubuntu3 (natty)]        
3)      tex-common [2.09 (natty)]               
4)      texlive-base [2009-11 (natty)]          
5)      texlive-binaries [2009-8ubuntu2 (natty)]
6)      texlive-common [2009-11 (natty)]        
7)      texlive-doc-base [2009-2 (natty)]       
8)      texlive-latex-base [2009-11 (natty)]    
9)      texlive-latex-base-doc [2009-11 (natty)]
10)     texlive-luatex [2009-11 (natty)]        

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] r 1
Rejecting the installation of lmodern version 2.004.1-3 (natty)
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

      Install the following packages:           
1)  R   lmodern [2.004.1-3 (natty)]             
2)      luatex [0.65.0-1ubuntu3 (natty)]        
...

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] r 10
Rejecting the installation of texlive-luatex version 2009-11 (natty)
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

      Install the following packages:           
1)  R   lmodern [2.004.1-3 (natty)]             
2)  R   luatex [0.65.0-1ubuntu3 (natty)]        
3)  R   tex-common [2.09 (natty)]               
4)  R   texlive-base [2009-11 (natty)]          
5)  R   texlive-binaries [2009-8ubuntu2 (natty)]
6)  R   texlive-common [2009-11 (natty)]        
7)  R   texlive-doc-base [2009-2 (natty)]       
8)  R   texlive-latex-base [2009-11 (natty)]    
9)  R   texlive-latex-base-doc [2009-11 (natty)]
10) R   texlive-luatex [2009-11 (natty)]        


Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] n
*** No more solutions available ***

The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

      Install the following packages:           
1)  R   lmodern [2.004.1-3 (natty)]             
2)  R   luatex [0.65.0-1ubuntu3 (natty)]        
3)  R   tex-common [2.09 (natty)]               
4)  R   texlive-base [2009-11 (natty)]          
5)  R   texlive-binaries [2009-8ubuntu2 (natty)]
6)  R   texlive-common [2009-11 (natty)]        
7)  R   texlive-doc-base [2009-2 (natty)]       
8)  R   texlive-latex-base [2009-11 (natty)]    
9)  R   texlive-latex-base-doc [2009-11 (natty)]
10) R   texlive-luatex [2009-11 (natty)]        


Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] y
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dropbox lmodern{a} luatex{a} tex-common{a} texlive-base{a} texlive-binaries{a} texlive-common{a} 
  texlive-doc-base{a} texlive-latex-base{a} texlive-latex-base-doc{a} texlive-luatex{a} 
The following partially installed packages will be configured:
  ipe 
0 packages upgraded, 11 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 87,4 MB of archives. After unpacking 181 MB will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] n
Abort.
```

So yeah - if I keep on rejecting all solutions, at the end I'll get "*** No more solutions available ***", and `aptitude` can either go with those solutions, or abort - but unfortunately cannot ignore them with this technique...