# Remove a package dependency permanently

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, texlive

**The Question:** How can I remove an `apt` package dependency permanently? (running Ubuntu 20.04)

#### My Example

I have TeX Live 2020 installed via TUG install script, the binaries are located in `/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux/`. Now I would like to install `ipe`. However, `ipe` has a dependency on `texlive-latex-base`, which I do not want to be installed (it is bulky and useless -- actually it installs the 2019 version at the moment).

What I figured out to do so far is to force-remove all `texlive` packages manually with

```
$ sudo dpkg -r --force-depends "texlive-latex-base"
$ sudo dpkg -r --force-depends "texlive-base"
$ sudo dpkg -r --force-depends "texlive-binaries"
```

and then manually remove the `ipe`'s dependency in `/var/lib/dpkg/status`.

However, this is not a permanent solution. Indeed, after running, e.g., an update, the `texlive` packages get installed automatically (probably by some black magic -- I even deleted the cached `.deb` packages) and the `status` file gets refreshed and the `texlive-latex-base` dependency of `ipe` emerges again.

N.b.: similar question here: [Ignoring specific unmet dependencies with aptitude?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/408696/ignoring-specific-unmet-dependencies-with-aptitude) but no relevant answer (i.e., no permanent solution asked and/or suggested).

Comment: The most creepy thing is that texlive gets installed even on background without any notification. This lead to situations like you compile once -- it works, you compile next time -- it fails (due to missing packages, obviously). So at least I would like to disable this kind of autoinstall.

Comment: Look at http://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html , under 'Integrating vanilla TeX Live with Debian' and also http://www.tug.org/texlive/files/debian-equivs-2020-ex.txt . The idea is that you create and install a dummy package that says that you have TL installed as a distribution package. This prevents the package system from installing the real TL distribution packages.

Comment: This works well for me, thanks! However, this is not an answer to the original question in general, in case someone needs it for any reason.

Comment: Equivs dummy packages can be created for any package, as far as I can make out.