# BeerorKid repositories doesn't work

Tags: repository

```
Reading package lists ... Error! 
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header 
E: Problem with MergeList / var/lib/apt/lists/www.beerorkid.com_compiz_dists_dapper_main-amd64_binary-i386_Packages 
E: Could not parse or open package lists or status file.
```

how to fix?
Because of this, it open almost nothing

I try to do an update and...

```
E: Error with GPG : http://www.beerorkid.com dapper Release : The following signatures were invalid : NODATA 1 NODATA 2
```

Comment: This isn't quite a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/30072/how-do-i-fix-a-problem-with-mergelist-or-status-file-could-not-be-parsed-err because in this case it's not just corruption. In this case it's the user has added a repo older than time itself. An answer needs to account for that repo before fixing the merge issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you are following [this guide](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=272180), first, you are following something for Dapper Drake 6.06 (6 years old) that doesn't apply to recent versions of Ubuntu. Second, you need to remove that repository:

> COMPIZ / BERYL
>   the repo on this server is out of date.
>   for beryl or compiz head to http://opencompositing.org/

Remove the repository using this:

```
sudo sed -i '/beerorkid/d' /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
sudo apt-get update
```

The opencompositing site also is dead (tried to get the repositories). I would also suggest you to upgrade Ubuntu and **don't use Dapper**.