# My Ubuntu Software Center Window Freezes?

Tags: 13.04

[image]

The Window keeps on loading,I've kept waiting for one hour.I'm using Ubuntu 13.04.I've used

```
     sudo update-software-center
```

But it does not work.

on running the Command: 
         software-center

```
     (software-center:4276): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-         widgets.css:202:26: 'none' is not a valid color name

     (software-center:4276): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:209:26: 'none' is not a valid color name

     (software-center:4276): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:217:26: 'none' is not a valid color name

     (software-center:4276): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:246:26: 'none' is not a valid color name

     (software-center:4276): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:253:26: 'none' is not a valid color name

     (software-center:4276): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:482:26: 'none' is not a valid color name

     (software-center:4276): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:501:26: 'none' is not a valid color name

    (software-center:4276): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:516:26: 'none' is not a valid color name

    (software-center:4276): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:529:26: 'none' is not a valid color name

    (software-center:4276): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1162:22: 'none' is not a valid color name

    (software-center:4276): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1167:22: 'none' is not a valid color name

    (software-center:4276): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1212:48: Expected ')'

    (software-center:4276): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1223:48: Expected ')'

    (software-center:4276): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1235:48: Expected ')'

    (software-center:4276): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1247:48: Expected ')'

    (software-center:4276): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1429:18: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

    (software-center:4276): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1437:18: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

    (software-center:4276): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1465:26: not a number

    (software-center:4276): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1474:26: not a number

    (software-center:4276): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1490:18: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

    (software-center:4276): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1535:5: '/*' in comment block

    (software-center:4276): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1921:22: 'none' is not a valid color name

    (software-center:4276): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-   widgets.css:1928:22: 'none' is not a valid color name
 2014-01-28 18:48:02,299 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
 2014-01-28 18:48:05,005 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - Could not get usefulness from server, no username in config file
 2014-01-28 18:48:05,038 - softwarecenter.plugin - INFO - activating plugin '<module   'webapps_activation' from '/usr/share/software-  center/softwarecenter/plugins/webapps_activation.pyc'>'
 2014-01-28 18:48:05,057 - softwarecenter.fixme - WARNING - logs to the root logger: '('/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/importer.py', 51, 'find_module')'
 2014-01-28 18:48:05,057 - root - ERROR - Could not find any typelib for    LaunchpadIntegration
 2014-01-28 18:48:05,308 - softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache - INFO -   aptcache.open()
```

Any help is appriciated. Thank you!

Comment: When you say does not work, what do you mean? Could you provide error messages, or does nothing appear, it just fails?

Comment: No error message,the window keeps on loading (provided in the image) and all the items are disabled,when i click the close button the window just closes.

Comment: After running the command: sudo update-software-center  , i cannon present the whole message after running, characters are bounded, but the last line is : E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.

Comment: try to install any package  and give us the output  ?

Answer (score 2):

**Uninstall Software Center:**

```
sudo apt-get purge software-center
```

**(IMPORTANT)Remember to remove the cache**

```
sudo rm -r ~/.cache/software-center
```

**Reinstall Software Center:**

```
sudo apt-get install software-center
```

Comment: Got error: Reading package lists... Error!
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring-updates_universe_i18n_Translation-en
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.            ----> from the first command.

Comment: there is a problem with your /etc/source.list file , point to it and check if there any syntax error

Comment: then run sudo apt-get update

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION:

wow, thanks for the support.
I've found the solution just now.Its beacsuse of my theme "Malys-deda". I've removed it and now it woks fine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling it, reinstalling will do software catalog update and may fix your problem

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall software-center
```

Software center is slow, you can try Deepin software center

http://www.noobslab.com/2013/07/deepin-software-center-version-30-and.html

Comment: Error:: E: Command line option 'r' [from -reinstall] is not known.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall software-center` my bad, it's with double dash

Comment: ok but again:                                                                  Reading package lists... Error!
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring-updates_universe_i18n_Translation-en
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.

Comment: check out this link http://askubuntu.com/questions/30072/how-do-i-fix-a-problem-with-mergelist-or-status-file-could-not-be-parsed-err