# "Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/repository.spotify.com_dists_stable_non-free_i18n_Translation-en%5fUS"

Tags: apt

I'm trying to install the google talk plugin on Ubuntu 14.04. I've been following this guide:

http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/google_talk_plugin

When I do the last step, *sudo apt-get install google-talkplugin*, I get the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/repository.spotify.com_dists_stable_non-free_i18n_Translation-en%5fUS
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

This doesn't make sense. What does Spotify have to do with installing Google Talk?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I fix a "Problem with MergeList" or "status file could not be parsed" error when trying to do an update?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/30072/how-do-i-fix-a-problem-with-mergelist-or-status-file-could-not-be-parsed-err)

Comment: It's not a duplicate. Solution from that question doesn't help here. This problem is Spotify specific and its connection with attempt to install google-talk is entirely coincidental.

Comment: @Ooker Googling the problem led me here as the first result ;)

Answer (score 10):

Spotify is having some problem with their repository URL being incorrectly resolved on DNS level. As a temporary solution replace the URL in your repositories list. By default, i.e. when installed from official Spotify instructions for Ubuntu users, you'll find it in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list`. For different distributions the line might be in `/etc/apt/sources.list` or in any of the files under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`. Change it to read as follows (mark the `-origin` part):

```
deb http://repository-origin.spotify.com stable non-free
```

Afterwards clean the apt lists cache and update as usual:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade
```

It should work.

Comment: Thanks! This worked. For some reason I didn't have a directory called sources.list.s, but I changed the one that was just in sources.list and that worked.

Comment: similar to the answer provided here: [link](http://community.spotify.com/t5/Help-Desktop-Linux-Mac-and/Spotify-0-9-11-for-GNU-Linux/m-p/845467#M91558)
Remove the spotify repository from software sources , then add spotify source with origin in name
In terminal

`sudo add-apt-repository -r "deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free"`

`sudo add-apt-repository "deb  http://repository-origin.spotify.com stable non-free"`

`sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf`
`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get upgrade`

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same issue - looks like Spotify's repository is fouled up, which makes the rest of Ubuntu upset. Tried copying /var/lib/dpkg/status and all the usual stuff, but still got complaints.

In the end, solved this by going to **Software & Updates** > **Other software** and unchecking the Spotify repository. Ran Software Updater again and it downloaded everything perfectly. I think Spotify have messed up on their end given that this is so widespread. Disable the Spotify repo, give it a day or two and see how it is then.

The search functionality seems to stop working after this, but I'm using the Web Player for the time being so no problem...

Answer (score -1):

The solution from Cyprian works great, apart from the line with rm which should be:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
```

Comment: Why? `-v` is `verbose mode` to print each and every removed file, it's unnecessary.

Comment: the `-f` flag does something, but is entirely unnecessary when working as root.