# Problem with mergelist

Tags: 14.04

Suddenly, my Ubuntu reports an error and no longer does updates because of this error. The error seems to be the following:

```
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_universe_i18n_Translation-en
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

It seems that this prevents me from doing everything. Apt-get stops with an error, synaptics manager also, and so on and so forth. Any solutions out there?

Thanks,

Jim

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/30072/how-do-i-fix-a-problem-with-mergelist-or-status-file-could-not-be-parsed-err

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
cd /var/lib/apt
sudo mv lists lists.old
sudo mkdir -p lists/partial
sudo apt-get update
```

This will reset the cache from scratch.

See if that fixes the issue. If it doesn't, you can revert the changes made above by doing the following:

```
cd /var/lib/apt
sudo rm lists
sudo mv lists.old lists
sudo rm -r lists/partial
```

Note: If the first part doesn't work the second command (`sudo rm lists`) may fail, that's OK.