# Single list item stopping package manager

Tags: apt, package-management, source-packages

Full error log:

starts here:

```
E:Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/ubuntu.c3sl.ufpr.br_ubuntu_dists_trusty_universe_i18n_Translation-pt%%5fBR (1),
```

The item above is from `universe` and the `binary` below relates to it.

```
E:Problem opening /var/lib/apt/lists/ubuntu.c3sl.ufpr.br_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages, E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

--and ends here.

It's not a merged list

It is happening in a brand new 14.04 Unity installation. Before I was running Ubuntu GNOME 14.04.

If I disable the `universe` repo I can update && upgrade without problems. It shows the relations between the items in the error. That is, without `universe` `src` does not have to parse the `binary` version of `universe_i18n`.

I'm running Package Manager Troubleshooting Procedures¹ to work around it meanwhile.
¹ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PackageManagerTroubleshootingProcedure

I wanna solve it. Any ideas?

Comment: ARe you certain it is not http://askubuntu.com/questions/30072/how-do-i-fix-a-problem-with-mergelist-or-status-file-could-not-be-parsed-err?

Answer (score 0):

What I suggest is clear the lists and obtain a fresh copy.

### Clear the List(s):

Command:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

### Obtain a Fresh Copy of Lists:

Command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

See if that rectifies the problem. :)

Comment: Norman Li, `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && sudo apt-get update` appears in several posts. Does not work.

Comment: That's essentially the same thing. :)
But yes, that should work. :)

Answer (score 0):

*Solved*

**system settings > programs & upgrades** # my system is in Portuguese

Go through all tabs and uncheck all sources (repos). Everything. It will comment the source.list and source.list.d/files* from top to bottom.

#### # The goal is to make a new source list

Close it with everything unchecked to make the system load an empty source

Close all apps and open a terminal `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`T`

`sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoclean`

Open **settings > programs** again and let Ubuntu **find the best source**. There is a **button** to do this.

Check the desired items in each tab

Close once again and reopen a terminal `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`T`

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

*Up and running*