# install some preinstall apps like (m4, csh,g++,gfortran)

Tags: 12.04

When I  try to install some pre-install apps like `m4, csh,g++,gfortran` on Ubuntu 12.04 (64 bit) before installing WRF model , I face with this problem:

```
sudo apt-get install m4
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_sun-java-community-team_sun-java6_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_binary-i386_Packages
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

What should I do ? How can I install these apps? I also, couldn't install `gfortran`.

I'll be thankful if you help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I fix a "Problem with MergeList" or "status file could not be parsed" error when trying to do an update?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/30072/how-do-i-fix-a-problem-with-mergelist-or-status-file-could-not-be-parsed-err)

Comment: okay, I see now that you were posting with http but the comments were auto formatted. You can prevent that by using ` marks on both ends so it will `post as code`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seriously need to get rid of that extremely outdated, insecure, unmaintained ppa. Open a terminal and execute the following commands:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sun*
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall m4 csh g++ gfortran
```

[If you would like to have an up to date sun java ppa I suggest this installer.](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java)

---

**EDIT**

Yes, you should fix that. First, run:

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.save
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> and type:

```
extras.ubuntu
```

and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

Now, the two lines should read **exactly**:

```
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
```

When you are done press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> and then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to save the file. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano.

Now, run the following commands to update your package list and to apply recent security updates and bug fixes:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Please post any errors, thanks.

Comment: thank you. I tried sudo apt-get update and I face with this error:W:" Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release  

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead".
                                                                                                    Is it important? however, I can install m4 ,csh ,g++ ,and gfortran.

Comment: @motti I have updated the answer, yes, it's pretty important to always make sure apt-get downloads all needed files.

Comment: mchid, thank you so much for your sincerely help.  I renamed the precise into trusty in line two and save it. After this, all following commands are worked. Now, update and upgrate commands are worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @motti awesome, you can accept this solution by clicking the icon on the left to mark the question as answered.