# Not opening Ubuntu Software Center 12.04

Tags: 12.04

```
    xapian_parser.set_database(self.xapiandb)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/database.py", line 162, in xapiandb
    self._db_per_thread[thread_name] = self._get_new_xapiandb()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/database.py", line 175, in _get_new_xapiandb
    xapiandb = xapian.Database(self._db_pathname)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xapian/__init__.py", line 3666, in __init__
    _xapian.Database_swiginit(self,_xapian.new_Database(*args))
xapian.DatabaseOpeningError: Couldn't stat '/var/cache/software-center/xapian' ***(No such file or directory)***
```

Comment: TRY `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf` and
`sudo apt-get update` in terminal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix a "Problem with MergeList" or "status file could not be parsed" error when trying to do an update?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/30072/how-do-i-fix-a-problem-with-mergelist-or-status-file-could-not-be-parsed-err)

Answer (score 0):

have you try Appgrid?

```
sudo apt-get install appgrid
```

or here : http://www.appgrid.org/

Much better than Software Center

Comment: Not installing                                                                                                          Reading package lists... Error!
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-updates_restricted_binary-i386_Packages
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.

Comment: Instead of just recommending a workaround to a major problem, it's probably better to actually provide a solution.