# installation of sshd in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: sshd

I am trying to install **sshd** on my Ubuntu system but I am unable to do so. I tried below things.

1. `sudo apt-get install openssh` but I received below error.
   [image]
2. When I am checking with which command for ssh, I am getting result for ssh but not for sshd.
3. While checking for status of ssh, I am getting an error of **unrecognized service**.

Please help me to overcome this as I am new to Ubuntu and I need both ssh and sshd to be available in my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSHD server is in `openssh-server` package. You need to install it this way, after fixing the [problem with MergeList](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30072/how-do-i-fix-a-problem-with-mergelist-or-status-file-could-not-be-parsed-err).

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```