# Apt-Get problems, software center crashes, can't update, install or uninstall programs

Tags: apt

After searching I have had no luck finding an answer to my issue...

Every related question I find says it's a duplicate of [This Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30072/how-do-i-fix-a-problem-with-mergelist-or-status-file-could-not-be-parsed-err), but I have not been able to resolve the issue through this thread...

Here is the output I recieve when running apt-get for ANY reason.

```
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Problem parsing dependency Depends
E: Error occurred while processing librhythmbox-core8 (NewVersion2)
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/dpkg/status
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

This just started happening today, and I had made absolutely no changes to my system beforehand... So I'm not sure where the problem came from.

I apologize if this is indeed a duplicate question, but I would really benefit from some direction in this case other than being pointed to a duplicate question... Or, maybe I just don't understand the answers given in the other thread???

Here is the out put from running :
sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update && dpkg -l | grep librhythmbox-core8

```
user@computer:~$ sudo apt-get clean
[sudo] password for user: 
user@computer:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                                  
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease [65.9 kB]           
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                              
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Get:2 http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg [72 B]                       
Hit http://repo.steampowered.com precise InRelease                             
Hit http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                    
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease [65.9 kB]          
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam Sources                         
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free amd64 Packages               
Ign https://private-ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources [110 kB]         
Ign https://private-ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam amd64 Packages                  
Hit http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free i386 Packages                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit https://private-ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease [65.9 kB]        
Hit https://private-ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit https://private-ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                           
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources [4,035 B]  
Hit http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam i386 Packages                   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit https://private-ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                           
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources [34.1 kB]    
Hit https://private-ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources [270 kB]        
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Sources [2,750 B]  
Hit https://private-ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages [448 kB] 
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US                     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit https://private-ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit https://private-ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Get:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources [5,352 B]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources [151 kB]   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Ign http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free Translation-en_US            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Get:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources [5,946 B]
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Ign http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free Translation-en               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Get:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages [740 kB]
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages [13.0 kB]
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Get:16 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages [125 kB]
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Get:17 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [4,991 B]
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Ign http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam Translation-en_US               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Get:18 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages [421 kB]  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Ign http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam Translation-en                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Get:19 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [15.9 kB]
Ign https://private-ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_US            
Ign https://private-ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en               
Get:20 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages [356 kB]
Ign https://private-ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_US            
Ign https://private-ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en               
Get:21 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages [12.7 kB]
Get:22 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages [125 kB]
Get:23 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [13.2 kB]
Get:24 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages [709 kB] 
Get:25 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages [5,175 B]
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_US                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Get:26 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en [244 kB] 
Get:27 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages [15.6 kB]
Get:28 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en [2,570 B]
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages [357 kB]
Get:30 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en [3,206 B]
Get:31 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en [73.9 kB]
Get:32 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [13.6 kB]
Get:33 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en [370 kB]
Get:34 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en [7,227 B]
Get:35 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en [3,699 B]
Get:36 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en [186 kB]
Get:37 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Sources [8,696 B]    
Get:38 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Sources [28 B] 
Get:39 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Sources [34.5 kB]
Get:40 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Sources [1,898 B]
Get:41 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages [9,782 B]
Get:42 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages [28 B]
Get:43 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages [41.3 kB]
Get:44 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages [1,571 B]
Get:45 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main i386 Packages [9,797 B]
Get:46 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages [28 B]
Get:47 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages [41.4 kB]
Get:48 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages [1,552 B]
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en          
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en      
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                           
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources                     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources                       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources                     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages                
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages               
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages                 
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages               
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en                
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US                 
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_US           
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_US           
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US             
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                      
Ign http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg
Ign http://dl.google.com stable Release
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages                             
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en
Fetched 5,197 kB in 11min 53s (7,284 B/s)
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Problem parsing dependency Depends
E: Error occurred while processing librhythmbox-core8 (NewVersion2)
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/dpkg/status
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
user@computer:~$ dpkg -l | grep librythmbox-core8
dpkg-query: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 47256 package 'libcupscgi1:amd64':
field name `'model' must be followed by colon
user@computer:~$
```

And here is the output of running ls -l /var/backups/dpkg.status.*

```
user@computer:~$ ls -l /var/backups/dpkg.status.*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2674043 Mar 22 00:46 /var/backups/dpkg.status.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  720501 Mar 20 15:14 /var/backups/dpkg.status.1.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  720493 Mar 10 21:50 /var/backups/dpkg.status.2.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  720031 Mar  7 01:24 /var/backups/dpkg.status.3.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  683814 Mar  4 02:13 /var/backups/dpkg.status.4.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  678609 Mar  4 01:52 /var/backups/dpkg.status.5.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  669474 Mar  2 22:54 /var/backups/dpkg.status.6.gz
user@computer:~$
```

Comment: what is the command that you issued?

Comment: I get this exact error with any command starting with apt-get, in this specific instance I was attempting to remove rhythmbox via 

     sudo apt-get remove rhythmbox

but i get the same for

     sudo apt-get update

also

Comment: what is the output of sudo apt-get clean ? the sudo apt-get update ?

Comment: what is the output of dpkg -l | grep librhythmbox-core8

Comment: The output of `ls -l /var/backups/dpkg.status.*` ?

Comment: @PascalFares I have added the output you asked for

Comment: @GAD3R I have also added the output you requested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following command:

```
cd /var/backups
head dpkg.status.0
gunzip dpkg.status.1.gz
head dpkg.status.1
cp /var/backups/dpkg.status.1 /var/lib/dpkg/status
head /var/lib/dpkg/status
apt-get update
```

Comment: Thank you so much! My system is now working properly!!! :D

Comment: I'm curious if you would mind explaining each of these commands you mentioned here? I know what cd means obviously, but would like to gain as much understanding about how I fixed the issue as possible... And again, thank you!

Comment: when you install a programm , update , upgrade , the current status will be saved on `/var/backups` as you can see you have sames `dpkg.status.x`sorted by date , we can try to restore the recent one. if dosn't work we try to restore the others.