# Error: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened

Tags: package-management

I don't know exactly what the problem is. I've attached the screen shot of the error. Please help how to solve it.
[image]

I also found that my CPU is running at 100% as per system manager.

after `sudo apt-get update` I am getting the following error:

`E: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release   amd64 (20160420.1)/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/boost-latest/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.`

Processes using TOP command :
[image]

Comment: Can you provide the context of the problem?

Comment: The above message in the image is the problem

Comment: I mean, which application where you running?

Comment: okay I am adding another Image of all the process running

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://askubuntu.com/q/30072/308164](http://askubuntu.com/q/30072/308164)...

Comment: I have tried the solution from you'r link. But it works partially error is not showing now, But my CPU is still on 100% what should I do now.

Comment: They are probably unrelated problems. If the above link solved your question, I suggest you create a new question with the CPU bit, deleting it from here, so we can mark this as duplicate.

Comment: okay, but after `sudo apt-get update` few packages are still unable to fetch

Comment: Can you add that info to the question?

Comment: added Sir, Failed to fetch cd Rom:

Comment: Ok, your sources file might not be correct. Will write an answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix a "Problem with MergeList" or "status file could not be parsed" error when trying to do an update?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30072/how-do-i-fix-a-problem-with-mergelist-or-status-file-could-not-be-parsed-err)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a problem with the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file. To evaluate this, let's create a new one that is clean.

- Open a terminal, and run the following:

  ```
  sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/source.list.backup
  ```

This creates a copy of the original file, just in case.

- Open the `sources.list` file with your preferred text editor. For example, with `gedit`. Delete all the content of the file, and copy this:

  ```
  deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt xenial main restricted universe multiverse
  deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
  deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
  deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse

  deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt xenial main restricted
  deb-src mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt xenial main restricted

  deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt xenial-updates main restricted
  deb-src mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt xenial-updates main restricted
  ```

This file includes the usual repositories to look at. I added the extra tweak of using the mirrors.txt file, which gives you the closest servers (the standard line is `http://com.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/`). If you want to generate a more presonalized sources list, use [this website](https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/index.php).

- Save, and update with `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: yes, after this everything is fetched, there's no  error

Comment: Good. What about the CPU usage? You can write another question.

Comment: I just used `sudo pkill process_name` to kill the process and now it's normal.

Comment: I think the two `deb` lines with `xenial main restricted` and `xenial-updates main restricted` lines are redundant. They are already mentioned in the first and second lines of the file, respectively.