# Installing updates are unsuccessful

Tags: updates

I was updating my ubuntu 12.04 and got few issues. I think something is broken that has to be fixed. Kindly help me to fix the issue when i run update command. I am receiving below errors.

```
W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs:
1397BC53640DB551

W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/restricted/source/Sources  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: `sudo rm -vf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

sudo apt-get update`  Running this did the trick. Got it resolved. Thx @Liso for the Link.

Answer (score 2):

Google dropped their support for i386, which is why this error shows up. As I assume you're 64-bit Ubuntu user will notice error that you mentioned already on your question.

For fix, the repository must be specifically set for 64-bit only. To do this, use convenience `sed` one-liner command, without having to modify file by hand:

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/deb http/deb [arch=amd64] http/' "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list"
```

For missing public key problem, you can try adding it back:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 1397BC53640DB551
```

[Wrong Sources List Entry or Malformed File For Chrome while using `apt-get update`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35770794/wrong-sources-list-entry-or-malformed-file-for-chrome-while-using-apt-get-upd)

[Fix failed to fetch Google Chrome](http://www.webupd8.org/2016/03/fix-failed-to-fetch-google-chrome_3.html)

Comment: I have executed the those commands.. It was successful. Later when i run  update command i am getting below errors `code`(
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en
Reading package lists... Error!                                                                                                      
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/extras.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_i18n_Translation-en
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.)

Comment: `Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_IN
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en
Reading package lists... Error!                                                                                                      
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/extras.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_i18n_Translation-en
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened`

Comment: You may want to see [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/30072/how-do-i-fix-a-problem-with-mergelist-or-status-file-could-not-be-parsed-err) for a possible fix, be aware though.

Comment: Thx @Liso, Link helped to resolve the issue. Now Every thing is working fine!!!!