# Help with error message from top right corner (Raspberry Pi 3)

Tags: gui, raspberrypi

I had a Raspberry Pi set up on a network for quite a while but it wasn't being used. I moved it and displayed it on a monitor. I cannot get the GUI network connection running or get hooked up to the internet. I'm not close enough to run an Ethernet connection. Is there anyway to get onto my home WiFi to fix this error?

Occasionally an error message pops up:

[image: 1]

Comment: possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/30072/how-do-i-fix-a-problem-with-mergelist-or-status-file-could-not-be-parsed-err

Comment: I did those two lines a few times, and during install I got the message:
`E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Comment: I also had a window pop up that says `There was a problem installing Package: libc6 2.23:Oubunto5` @Kevin Bowen

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix a "Problem with MergeList" or "status file could not be parsed" error when trying to do an update?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30072/how-do-i-fix-a-problem-with-mergelist-or-status-file-could-not-be-parsed-err)