# How do I install and use Times New Roman Font with LibreOffice Writer?

Tags: apt, package-management, libreoffice

**I need the font for my ebook.**

I have looked around for questions similar to this. Unfortunately, when I try to use the commands in the terminal I am greeted with this:

> Reading package lists... Error!
>
> E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_main_i18n_Translation-en%5fUS (1)
>
> E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_main_i18n_Translation-en (1)
>
> E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_restricted_binary-all_Packages (1)
>
> E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-
>   updates_restricted_i18n_Translation-en%5fUS (1)
>
> E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_restricted_i18n_Translation-en (1)
>
> E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_universe_binary-all_Packages (1)
>
> E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.
>   com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_universe_i18n_Translation-en%5fUS (1)
>
> E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_multiverse_i18n_Translation-en%5fUS (1)
>
> E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_multiverse_i18n_Translation-en (1)
>
> E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_partner_binary-amd64_Packages (1)
>
> E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_partner_binary-i386_Packages (1)
>
> E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_partner_binary-all_Packages (1)
>
> E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
>
> E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_partner_i18n_Translation-en%5fUS
>
> E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.

**Does any one have the latest way to get and install them, preferably with ease?**

EDIT: *This is not the same as the other due to the other options not working and actually disabling LibreOffice Writer on my computer, which I am now trying to fix. Here is a link to that question:*

[LibreOffice Writer will not open?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/946624/libreoffice-writer-will-not-open)

Comment: And for fixing the immediate problem: https://askubuntu.com/questions/30072/how-do-i-fix-a-problem-with-mergelist-or-status-file-could-not-be-parsed-err and similar answers

Comment: Have you tried sudo apt update, and then reinstalling the package?  sudo apt install --reinstall package-name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy way to add fonts...

- open the `terminal` application
- `cd`
- `ls .fonts`
- if .fonts folder doesn't exist, create it...
- `mkdir .fonts`
- move a folder of Times New Roman fonts into .fonts folder

Comment: Is there a specific place that I need to add the folder to or will any do?

Comment: If you follow my instructions, it'll go into the correct place, the top of /home/your_username. Please remember to accept the answer if it works for you. Thanks!