# LibreOffice Writer will not open?

Tags: apt, libreoffice

**I tried to install Microsoft Fonts through the terminal and now LibreOffice Writer will not work!**

I was trying to get Times New Roman on LibreOffice Writer, so I used the command:

```
sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

The terminal ran it and everything "finished" but nothing happened. I tried to open LibreOffice Writer and it would display the icon *LibreOffice 5* before disappearing and not opening the program. I thought that it was the installer's doing, so I ran the code to supposedly get rid of it. That code/command was:

```
sudo apt-get remove ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

Now I'm sitting here, trying to get it to work, but I'm getting the same results.

For reference, when I used the first command the following appeared:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ttf-mscorefonts-installer is already the newest version (3.4+nmu1ubuntu2).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gyp lib32gcc1 lib32stdc++6 libc6-i386 libjs-inherits libjs-node-uuid
  libssl-dev libssl-doc libuv1-dev node-abbrev node-ansi node-ansi-color-table
  node-archy node-async node-block-stream node-combined-stream node-cookie-jar
  node-delayed-stream node-forever-agent node-form-data node-fstream
  node-fstream-ignore node-github-url-from-git node-glob node-graceful-fs
  node-gyp node-inherits node-ini node-json-stringify-safe node-lockfile
  node-lru-cache node-mime node-minimatch node-mkdirp node-mute-stream
  node-node-uuid node-nopt node-normalize-package-data node-npmlog node-once
  node-osenv node-qs node-read node-read-package-json node-request node-retry
  node-rimraf node-semver node-sha node-sigmund node-slide node-tar
  node-tunnel-agent node-underscore node-which nodejs-dev npm zlib1g-dev
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 483 not upgraded.
```

When I entered the command to remove it, it displayed this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gyp lib32gcc1 lib32stdc++6 libc6-i386 libjs-inherits libjs-node-uuid
  libssl-dev libssl-doc libuv1-dev node-abbrev node-ansi node-ansi-color-table
  node-archy node-async node-block-stream node-combined-stream node-cookie-jar
  node-delayed-stream node-forever-agent node-form-data node-fstream
  node-fstream-ignore node-github-url-from-git node-glob node-graceful-fs
  node-gyp node-inherits node-ini node-json-stringify-safe node-lockfile
  node-lru-cache node-mime node-minimatch node-mkdirp node-mute-stream
  node-node-uuid node-nopt node-normalize-package-data node-npmlog node-once
  node-osenv node-qs node-read node-read-package-json node-request node-retry
  node-rimraf node-semver node-sha node-sigmund node-slide node-tar
  node-tunnel-agent node-underscore node-which nodejs-dev npm zlib1g-dev
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  ttf-mscorefonts-installer
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 483 not upgraded.
After this operation, 134 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 247063 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing ttf-mscorefonts-installer (3.4+nmu1ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for update-notifier-common (3.168.4) ...
```

**What do I do to fix this? I have a lot of documents made with LibreOffice Writer and I don't want to lose them!**

Comment: **483 not upgraded** !!! Please fully update your system - something you should do *before* installing anything - and try again. Installing MS Fonts has nothing to do with it and removing the installer does nothing, i.e., it only remove the installer itself, the meta-package, not the fonts it installed but again those should be no problem. If the problem persists after updating then come back and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Please open a terminal window and run `lowriter`. Any errors that are causing LibreOffice to crash should be displayed in the terminal -- let us know what it says.

Comment: @MichaelBay  How would I full update my system?

Comment: Either open the Updates or the terminal and run `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt full-upgrade`.

Comment: Once you have fully updated your system, if you still experience this crash, please file a bug report by running `ubuntu-bug libreoffice` in a terminal and following the instructions.