# Unable to remove the packages in ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, virtualbox, uninstall

When I try to remove the virtual box installed on ubuntu as follow,

`sachin-verma@sachin-verma:~$ sudo apt-get remove virtualbox-5.1`

Then it shows following errors:

```
Reading package lists... Error!
N: Ignoring file '50unattended-upgrades.ucf-dist' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'getdeb.list.bck' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-amd64_Packages
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Please help me out ?

PS.- This is also happening, when I am trying to uninstall other packages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix a "Problem with MergeList" or "status file could not be parsed" error when trying to do an update?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30072/how-do-i-fix-a-problem-with-mergelist-or-status-file-could-not-be-parsed-err) Please delete '50unattended-upgrades.ucf-dist' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' and 'getdeb.list.bck' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' with command of type `sudo rm file-name` to remove the warnings on lines 2 and 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move problematic file out the way with

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades.ucf-dist ~/
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list.bck ~/
```

clear APT lists with

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/*
```

and retry to get new package lists with

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then finally remove unneeded package(s) with

```
sudo apt-get remove virtualbox-5.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the commands in the Terminal

Command to remove merge list:

```
$ sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
```

Here, `-v` stands for verbose which will explain what is being done and`-f` stands for force which will ignore nonexistent files and arguments and would never prompt

Now Update,

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Remove Virtualbox,

```
$ sudo apt-get remove virtualbox* --purge
```