# Every time I try to install a package, I get this error

Tags: boot, apt, package-management, dpkg

```
E: Problem parsing dependency 53 of libmat io-doc:all=1.5.17-3
E: Error occured while processing libmat io-doc (NewVersion2)
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal_universe_binary-amd64_Packages
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened
```

Also note that I cancelled e2fsck before this and that I cannot get into login screen, I get stuck on fsck: /dev/sda5 clean:xxx/xxx files, then the screen goes to blank then fsck thing over and over again, and I'm currently in root recovery mode trying to download a package [just thought this might be of help.]

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which release?

Comment: Yes, I am using Ubuntu

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/30072/how-do-i-fix-a-problem-with-mergelist-or-status-file-could-not-be-parsed-err
This answered it, if you'd like to get the answer, there you go.