# How do I fix a malformed status line?

Tags: 22.04

I have 22.04. I was trying to set up the virtual machine and this error keeps popping up. And I can't seem to get back to the source list to correct this. Here is the error:

```
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Malformed Status line
E: Error occurred while processing eveusb (UsePackage3)
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/dpkg/status
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Can someone please help me? I'm pretty new at this and I would really appreciate your help. Thank you!

UPDATE: Okay i put this

```
sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/status-old /var/lib/dpkg/status
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and now it shows this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: The package eveusb needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

Comment: The new output seems very clear. What's your question about it? Did you search for other questions about that message?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix a "Problem with MergeList" or "status file could not be parsed" error when trying to do an update?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30072/how-do-i-fix-a-problem-with-mergelist-or-status-file-could-not-be-parsed-err)